# My Application crashes when there is no active internet data plan

Tags: android

I have just created an application which makes connection to a webservice. But I notice that when it is on the device. When there is no active internet on the user device. My application crashes cos it can not make a connection to the internet web service. Though in my code I have been able to check when the internet is turned off.

So I am tinking of using this code to check if I can connect to url before I make the connection. Please what is the best way to check if there is a active data plan on device.
Or I am I doing the right way.

```
public ValidateUrlConnection(String urlAddress){

        try{
            url = new URL(urlAddress);
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

well you cannot check if the device had a data plan you can however check if there is an active connection using `ConnectivityManager`

```
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
```

Comment: If there is no active data plan. The network provider would prevent your application from connecting. rite so I was thinking I should query the Url first before making any GET or Post to it. So if the connection breaks I display a info the user telling him or her to check internet speed or megabyte plan. There could be a better way that is Why I am asking.

Comment: I just gave you the better way use the `ConnetivityManager` to see if there is internet

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to check the internet connection before call the url

Connectiondetecter.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.util.Log;

public class ConnectionDetector {

private Context _context;

public ConnectionDetector(Context context){
    this._context = context;
}
public boolean isConnectingToInternet(){
    ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) _context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
      if (connectivity != null)
      {
          NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
          if (info != null)
              for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                  if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                  {
                      Log.d("Network", "NETWORKnAME: "+info[i].getTypeName());
                      return true;
                  }

      }
      return false;
}}
```

Shaow Alert box if no internet connection

Alert.java

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;

public class AlertDialogManager {

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void showAlertDialog(Context context, String title, String message, Boolean status) {
    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle(title);

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage(message);

    if (status != null)
        // Setting alert dialog icon
        alertDialog.setIcon((status) ? R.drawable.success : R.drawable.fail);

    // Setting OK Button
    alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

}

and then check the internet connection as:

```
ConnectionDetector cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());


if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
        alert.showAlertDialog(youractivity.this, "Internet Connection Error",
                "Please connect to working Internet connection", false);
        return;
    }
else
{
 do_your_internet_task()
}
```